# What resolves Zeno's argument for the non-existence of place?

Tags: aristotle, paradox, zeno-of-elea, relations

Aristotle discusses six dialectical arguments for the non-existence of place in [*Physics* bk. Δ On Place, ch. 1 (209<sup>a</sup>)](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/Physics4.htm#2); Zeno's argument is #5:

> if everything that exists has a place, place too will have a place, and so on *ad infinitum*

Does what I call "idempotence of place" resolve the paradox?:

Place is an idempotent relation because the the place of the place of something is still its place. Thus place(place)=place. Therefore place(place(place(…)))=place.

Comment: (1) You should be more formal. Your use of symbol is a bit ambiguous. (2) Mathematically speaking it's not *transitivity* but rather looks like *idempotence* (3) You should think about what it means to "resolve the paradox"

Comment: Agreed it is idempotence.

Comment: Aristotle considers the idea that a place is not a part of that whose place it is to be one of our basic intuitions about "place". So this proposal would be a non-starter for him, see [Aristotle on Space, Time, and Motion](http://physics.bgsu.edu/~gcd/Spacetime5.html)

Comment: @BorisEng but I'd be inclined to think idempotent functions are transitive under composition so you're at least half-right.

Comment: Why do you think that there is a paradox at all ? A., [*Phy*, IV 4, 212a20-21](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/physics.4.iv.html) "the place of a thing is the innermost motionless boundary of what contains it." *Boundary* does not mean that it is a *thing* itself. Thus, if place is not a thing, there is no need of "the place" of *place*.

Comment: If you agree that this is about idempotence and not transitivity, please [edit] your post to clarify that. Also, I believe your last expression 'place(place(place(...)))=place' should actually read something like 'place(place(...(place)...))=place', to avoid plugging in something else than a place.

Comment: @Keelan In response to your first question, the reason I don't edit is because I agree it's idempotence, but I don't agree that it's not transitivity. It seems idempotent functions are transitive under composition. On your 2nd point, I see where you're coming from but I prefer the theorem in its more general form so you can put (place) in its heart but you could put anything there and the identity still holds.

Comment: I feel that there is no resolution. Zeno's particular arguments may be resolvable in some cases, but the paradoxical nature of out notions of time and place remains a problem. Paradoxes arise when we reify time and space and they imply that we shouldn't do so. .

Comment: @BorisEng I changed my mind, I've changed it to idempotence.

Comment: Formally, idempotence does solve the paradox (to the extent that it is a paradox). This is not much, however, because one can usually "solve" paradoxes with _ad hoc_ assumptions.
What is missing is an argument that place(place) = place is not an _ad hoc_ assumption. That is, a convincing conceptual analysis, showing _why_ place(place) = place, independently of Zeno's paradox.

Comment: @Boris I guess in general to resolve a paradox is to prove that sound argument is not inherently contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

Aristotle resolves the argument in [*Physics* bk. Δ On Place, ch. 3 (210<sup>b</sup>)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Physics4.htm#4):

> Zeno's problem—that if Place is something it must be in something—is not difficult to solve. There is nothing to prevent the first place from being 'in' something else—not indeed in that as 'in' place, but as health is 'in' the hot as a positive determination of it or as the hot is 'in' body as an affection. So we escape the infinite regress.

---

<sup>For an in-depth treatment of the "problem" of place, see "Part II: Place" of:</sup>

- <sup>Duhem, Pierre Maurice Marie. [*Medieval Cosmology: Theories of
  Infinity, Place, Time, Void, and the Plurality of Worlds*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4757). Edited
  and translated by Roger Ariew. Chicago: University of Chicago Press,
  1985.</sup>